# How to split these data by generating new columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 35 columns and data is  similar to this sample

```html
df<-read.table (text=" Id Name Group   MN  AZ  KL  Norm
2  John  P1  12  7   17  21
11  Sarah W1  11  8   12  20
2   John L1  13  9   19  20
11  Sarah N1  14  12  16  18
", header=TRUE)
```

I want to get these data:

```html
id  Name    Group1  MN1 AZ1 KL1 Norm1   Group2  MN2 AZ2 KL2 Norm2
2   John    P1  12  7   17  21  L1  13  9   19  20
11  Sarah   W1  11  8   12  20  N1  14  12  16  18
```

The data split by Group. I there a solution to sort these data either by basic rcodes or just dplyr. As you can see the column Name is not split

Answer (score 1):

It is not advised to have dataframe with similar column names. For each `Id` we can create a row number column which can be appended to column names in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = row, values_from = Group:Norm) %>%
  select(Id, order(readr::parse_number(names(.))))

#     Id Group_1  MN_1  AZ_1  KL_1 Norm_1 Group_2  MN_2  AZ_2  KL_2 Norm_2
#  <int> <chr>   <int> <int> <int>  <int> <chr>   <int> <int> <int>  <int>
#1     2 P1         12     7    17     21 L1         13     9    19     20
#2    11 W1         11     8    12     20 N1         14    12    16     18
```

`parse_number` returns a warning since `Id` does not have number but it is safe to ignore that.

---

You can also use `data.table` if ordering of columns is not important.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), Id~rowid(Id), value.var = c('Group', 'MN', 'AZ', 'KL', 'Norm'))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c(2L, 11L, 2L, 11L), Group = c("P1", "W1", 
"L1", "N1"), MN = c(12L, 11L, 13L, 14L), AZ = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 12L
), KL = c(17L, 12L, 19L, 16L), Norm = c(21L, 20L, 20L, 18L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thank you, data. table is interesting, but  how we could do it for many columns

Comment: dplyr is not encouraging when you have many columns

Comment: The answer already works for many columns as shown with the data in my answer. Can you provide your data in an unambiguous format using `dput` ?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated. The issue is that it does not reflect the intended outcome. is it possible to it with data.table for multiple columns?

Comment: For the data that you have shared the answer still works, right? Do you mean to change the order of the columns because that is the only thing different in my answer.

Comment: Hmm.....Can you check then how is the data that you have shared is different from your actual data? What should be the values in place of those `NA`'s?

Comment: For the data you have shown does my answer give you intended outcome?

Comment: What is missing in my output? I can't find it.

Comment: Ordering is missing

Comment: @user330 Updated the answer with required ordering.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question about repeating two columns for each group.

Comment: The issue is that when I run for 35 columns, the column names do not appear like this small data. Hopefully, somebody helps me.

Comment: As I said it is difficult to correct an answer if we don't know what the issue is. The answer works for the sample data but it does not for your original data then something is different between the data shared and the data you have. Can you find out what that is?